# how send event from some class?

Tags: android

I have some class that implement a state machine.
When some state is change i want to send some event to all the classes that listen to this event

How can i do it ?

I looking for some simple way like that do it on C#

```
    public event EventHandler NotifyStatusChange;

     private void NotifyStateChanged()
    {
        if( NotifyStatusChange != null )
        {
            NotifyStatusChange( this, new ObjectStatusEventArgs( lastStatus, currentStatus ) );
        }
    }
```

Comment: see https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Scala akka actors would seem perfect. Simple, clean and compiles down to ART.

Comment: Local Broadcast, event bus, or RxJava Observable.  If you need to go cross process, then BroadcastReceivers.

Comment: Try with `Service`.